# Webview Link to App Launch Crashes WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have a webview that loads an external URL. This site has a link within it that attempts to launch a specific app on the users device when clicked. Though rather than launching the app it crashes the webview.

I've tested this same site in Chrome and it will work as expected, meaning, it launches the app.

How can I mimic that same action in webview?

Comment: what is the error log?

Answer (score 0):

WebViews simply don't handle custom URI schemes by default if that is what you are using to launch your app on Chrome.

You will have to override [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and test if the URL uses your URI scheme, launching your app and returning true if it matches, otherwise returning false.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(context);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (request.getUrl().getScheme().startsWith("myscheme")) {
                //launch app

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().startsWith("myscheme")) {
                //launch app

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
);
```